# Difference between 'podría estar' and 'estaría'

Tags: verbos, condicional, indicativa

This question could apply to a number of verbs I guess, including:

> podría ser OR sería
>
> podría hablar OR hablaría
>
> podría comer OR comería

Which could be generalised as '***conditional indicative OR cond. ind. of poder + infinitive***'

Are there any differences between these? Are there common contexts or uses where one is more suitable than the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are different. *Podría ser* is *could be*, whereas *sería* is *would be*:

> - Si fuera rico, *podría comer* ostras a diario = If I were rich, I *could eat* oysters every day.
> - Si fuera rico, *comería* ostras a diario = If I were rich, I *would eat* oysters every day.

Comment: This is correct. But in some cases both verbal forms can be used with the same sense: "me comería un sandwish ahora", "podría comerme un sandwich ahora", in both cases the subject is indicating in a figurative way that he is hungry.

Comment: If you say "comería..." if you had the chance you'd definitely eat; but if you say "podría comer..." if you had the chance you'd be able to eat but you'd decide at that moment whether eating or not.